# Debugging Knockout Select Value

Tags: debugging, select, knockout.js

How is it possible to debug a select value using knockoutjs? My attempt to use `data-bind="change: function(){debugger}` does not seem to be working.

```
<p data-bind="visible: $data[$item.settings.name]['navigation_type']() == 0" >
  Link to Screen:<br/><select name="screen" data-bind="change: function(){debugger}, options: $item.element().screen.flow.navigable_screens, optionsText: function(item) { return item.attributes.name();}, optionsValue: 'permanent_id', value: $data[$item.settings.name].permanent_id"></select>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately knockout doesn't work the way you appear to try to be using it. I'm assuming from this bit of code: `data-bind="change:` you are trying to bind to the jquery change event?  If so, take a look at how select lists work here:

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html

and here:

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/simpleList.html

Knockout is much more elegant than jQuery, but follows the MVVM pattern instead of using jQuery events. I would suggest getting a highlevel understanding of the MVVM pattern, along with working through all the tutorials at http://learn.knockoutjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar issues debugging the inline value bindings that KnockoutJS uses.  On my most recent project, I implemented a loose binding pattern as explained here:

http://addyosmani.com/blog/understanding-mvvm-a-guide-for-javascript-developers/

You can declare all your bindings in JS and thus debug them.  You then reference them with a custom data- attribute in your html.

Comment: Great link dude, I was just looking for something like that. +1 Though it looks like he is trying to mix data-binds in a strange way

Comment: It does seem a little strange at first and you have to be careful about your binding names, but it works great.  My markup is 100% cleaner now, and our error logs will be much more meaningful.

Comment: Nice.  Glad that the custom binding provider is useful.